# Scandroid steganography: "Alter the extension of a new beginning in order to READ what the others can only SEE"

Tags: jpeg, steganography

So, for some quick background, one of my favorite musicians, Scandroid, put out a riddle that states "If you alter the extension of a new beginning, you can READ what others can only SEE."  When you purchased the song from their label's website, you got a bonus picture.  the picture was titled "Origins" (New beginning) so i had the idea to convert the .jpg file to a .txt and just see if there was a hidden message.  Inside I found some unusual coding that my friend seems to think is in java language, and thinks it may be an audio file because there are some stream commands.  unfortunately neither of us have the skill to separate this coding, nor do we know how to use it in the way it was intended.  Below is a link to a google doc that contains the segments of the .txt file that seemed unusual to me.  Please note, the segments were separated by quite some space inside the txt file.  If you would like to take a look at the whole file feel free to give me your E-Mail and i will be glad to send it to you.  Thanks in advance - Pat D.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nTTfxcrNZRtb9otybuG4VAhJRFlnAmfBnuTDE1o43UM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: A question should be self-contained: no external resources should be necessary to understand your question. Please edit your question to include all relevant information.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving a riddle not related to programming.

Comment: Any idea as to how I could view the message?

Comment: I agree with user2864740 about the nature of the question. I also don't see how the jpeg and steganography tags are relevant. If anything, it should be the `file-extension` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Its a pdf file. You should be able to open it with Adobe Acrobat Reader.